# At which color temperature and intensity can LED lighting be safe?

Tags: led-lights

An LED light panel uses 128 LED beads, has an adjustable color temperature range from 3300K to 5500K, and an adjustable brightness range from 10% to 100%.

Sources like the one at the link below state that nearsightedness, eye strain, and poor sleep are some of the effects of exposure to LED lights. https://health.clevelandclinic.org/are-led-lights-damaging-your-retina/

That makes it seem that the more direct the exposure is and the more bright the exposure is, the more it affects the eyes.

Are there any color temperatures and brightness ranges of LED lights which are safe for human eyes for use on a daily basis for recording videos and online streaming?

Is there anything additional that can be done to use such lights while eliminating or minimizing the negative effects of using LED lights such as some type of filters, glasses, etc?

Comment: What are these negative effects you speak of? Did you read something saying LED lights are harmful?

Comment: Sources like the one at the link below state that nearsightedness, eye strain, and poor sleep are some of the effects of exposure to LED lights. https://health.clevelandclinic.org/are-led-lights-damaging-your-retina/ So it seems that the more direct the exposure is and the more bright the exposure is to the eyes, the more effects.

Comment: You need to edit your question and make that link part of it. It explains the reason for your question and demonstrates prior research.

Comment: @Matty From the page you linked: “Thus far, there is no true, strong study to show either way that it is harmful or beneficial,” explains Dr. Singh. “We haven’t had a marker of structural damage to the retina from these lighting technologies. So right now, we can’t recommend that people stop using them.” Of course, *any* type of light at a strong enough intensity can cause damage.